# jQuery carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

as so many other people I am looking for a carousel for my homepage. 
I already had a look at the market.

My favorite would be a mix of several existings ones. And, if possible, it should be based on jQuery, since I am using that already. Some good carousels are based on mootools, though.

So, what do I like?
[noobSlide](http://www.efectorelativo.net/laboratory/noobSlide/) is nice. Perfect would be the a mix from 6 and 7: 6 has the larger picture with some overlay and link. 7 has the parallel positioning of the images. Problem: I have >50 not 8, so I would need some kind of slider. 
[SmoothGallery](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/showcase/gallery/) has a nice slider (after clicking on pictures).

So, with the requirements

- larger picture with overlay (infos + link(s))
- horizontal slider control with scrolling
- If possible, jQuery

Where would you send me? Some cool component/library I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like carousel on this page:

http://www.adventure-service.com/

I'm using this plugin:

http://thomlx.free.fr/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

Just include that javascript file, put html as follows:

```
                    <div id='banner_container'>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src='' alt='' /></li>
                            <li><img src='' alt='' /></li>
                            <li><img src='' alt='' /></li>
                            <li><img src='' alt='' /></li>
                            <li><img src='' alt='' /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Make a call to this function:

```
        $('#banner_container').carousel();
```

And that's it. If you want for example auto slide and buttons so you can click on each button and coresponding image to show up:

```
        $('#banner_container').carousel({
            autoSlide: true, 
            autoSlideInterval: 4000,
            pagination: true
        });
```

Comment: I tried you above solution but it does not work. Only the First image gets loaded into the carousel but I press next button no image slides in. Why is it? **Please help.**

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like it to be fully keyboard accessible, try [KATC](http://se-katc.appspot.com).