# Jquery carousel a la Google Chrome Web Store

Tags: jquery, carousel

I really like the carousel on the Google Chrome Web Store.
It is beautiful, neat and very effective.
Here is an example:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cnneehghmdakbiinndechnolpjocoecc

I would really like to replicate it with JQuery on my website.

What [stable and reliable] plugin can I use to implement that exactly as it is or, at least, something very very similar?

I already know JCarousel but I would like something neater and nicer.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172991/jquery-carousel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **[Infinite Carousel 2](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/12/30/huge-updates-to-jquery-infinite-carousel-version-2-released/)**?

Comment: Is there option when you can display half of previous/next  image or content on left and right side just like Google Chrome store has. (For specific screen resolution of course)