# Chrome web store like image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Anyone has any information how to make image gallery like Chrome webstore?

[chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aggljnipbdiebhbmadknfbjlhehbohbn?hc=hp&hcp=pop)

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a link to another question that speaks to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482441/jquery-carousel-a-la-google-chrome-web-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Infinite Carousal plugin is pretty handy for this and has been about a while so should be stable.

[Infinite Carousal](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/12/30/huge-updates-to-jquery-infinite-carousel-version-2-released/)

Comment: Sorry g_thom, didn't see your comment :( Points to pretty much exactly the same place!