# How to Achieve this Carousel Effect Using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, slider, cycle, carousel

I want to know how I can create something like this flash carousel using jQuery:

[link to the flash file](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/drupal_34524/sites/all/themes/theme556/flash/header_v8.swf?xmlUrl=/drupal_34524/sites/all/themes/theme556/flash/)

Can it be done using jQuery Cycle, jQuery Tools or jCarousel?

Any comments will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: See the links on the right-hand-side of this page? Click on them. They are similar questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172991/jquery-carousel)

Comment: IMHO, stay away from jQuery Tools.  Way out of date with jQuery and poorly designed.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Cycle is able to do this, you can animate custom css attributes when slides change in and out. However JQuery Cycle takes a good bit of programming out of the box. Here is a tutorial site that shows how to make some pretty cool scripts:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/

Answer (score 0):

[MovingBoxes](http://chriscoyier.github.com/MovingBoxes/) might be what you want.